# React plotly bar chart: color bars dependend on x value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, bar-chart

I got the following code:

```
 x: [1, 2, 3,4],
 y: ['Who?', 'Where?', 'When?','What?'],
 name: 'Subject',
 orientation: 'h',
 marker: {
   color: 'rgba(55,128,191,0.6)',
   width: 1
 },
 type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1];
var layout = {
 title: 'Colored Bar Chart',
 barmode: 'stack'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud:true});
```

The label 'Who?' should be red, 'Where?' should be orange, 'When?'should be yellow and 'What?' should be green. How do I archive this?
I already looked at colorscale but couldnt make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#bar-marker-color

> Sets themarkercolor. It accepts either a specific color or an array of
>   numbers that are mapped to the colorscale relative to the max and min
>   values of the array or relative to `marker.cmin` and `marker.cmax` if
>   set.

Like this:

```
marker: {
  color: ['#ff0000', '#ff2200', 'rgba(55,128,191,0.6)', '#00ff00'],
  width: 1
},
```

First color in array corresponds to first bar, 2nd to 2nd, etc

Comment: but if i have 20 questions i need to define 20 colors. Cant the value on the x-axis controll the color which is displayed?

Comment: @OnlyX what do you mean? You can generate an array of colors using any algoritm

Comment: I want to assign 4 colors to every Question depending on the x axis value.Isnt there a way to color the bar in dependency to its value?

Comment: @OnlyX I'm not sure I understand you correctly but I prepared an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dust-0sk4b). In example color depends on `y` but can depend on anything.